# new ios app type

Tags: ios

when I try to add a new app in ituneconnect/manage your applications, there is no option to upload iphone screen shot, so I can only upload ipad screen shot, does this mean I can only submit ipad app? what do I miss? thanks.

Comment: Did you make your app iPad-only by mistake? Check the target's summary in Xcode. What is selected for "Devices"? Universal or iPad?

Comment: @rmaddy He says he's adding a new app, if that's the case..shouldn't it always be universal until you upload binary?

Comment: @mkral Hmmm. I was thinking about this as if the binary had already been uploaded and then the screenshots were being loaded. But if this is before the binary has been uploaded, there should be no need to add any screen shots, right?

Comment: @rmaddy Yea, that must be what happened. He created app without screenshots then went to upload iPad-only.

Comment: I haven't uploaded the binary yet, I was trying to upload some iphone screen shot but found it is not an option...

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots needed are normally based on the devices family you have set in your `app binary` (this is what you have set in your target's summary of XCode).

I believe you should still be able to download the screenshots for IPhones if you haven't upload your binary when you are trying to upload your screenshots in iTunes connect. May be can you add to your post the screenshot of the upload section (in your app summary)? Take a look to `Uploading Icons, Screenshots, and Routing App Files for Your App` in the [adding new apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html) reference guide also, they are referring there the list of screenshots you can upload when creating a new app.